# How can I get an <img> element to re-evaluate its onerror?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onerror

I have an  element with an onerror attribute that sets it to an image if its src is not found. This works great, but I want that onerror logic to be re-evaluated when the image's src is modified via javascript.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include the code for your `onerror` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`obj.onerror()` <--that should do it</strike>

---

**Scratch that**

It does it automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/FsFmf/ (tested in Chrome 13)

Comment: Hmm... the source is being set via jquery (probably should have said that initially) like this: $('#previewIMG').attr("src", prev); and the the src is definitely not changed to the error value afterwards. Here's the onerror attribute: onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='broken.png';return false;" Do you think that using JQuery would matter?

Comment: @Mike, why are you nuking your `onerror` in your `onerror` handler? (`this.onerror=null`)

Comment: @cvsguimaraes -- what that fiddle for??

Comment: Gah, it was right there in front of me. Not my code, I'm just fixing a bug with it, but that should have been obvious.

There's no value in this question, right? I should just delete it?

Comment: Thank you both for your help, BTW.

Comment: @Mike why delete it? you found the answer, no?

Comment: Well, it's very specific to this exact situation. It doesn't seem like it would be that useful to anyone else, and would only be clutter.

Comment: @Mike -- so flag your question with a message for the mods

Comment: Mario’s answer is hundred times simpler and works. Why was this one accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Locate your **img** element with getElementById() for example.

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('theImg');
```

Then

```
imgElement.addEventListener('error',
    function()
    {
        alert('Error, could not be loaded.');
        // ...whatever else you want to happen if not found.
    }
    , 1);
```

That will do it.